# How to load AMD modules inside my non-AMD AngularJS app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dojo, amd

I have an AngularJS app, which does not use any AMD library since Angular's dependency injection is all what I need for a good architecture. I was inspired for this design by an [article on medium.com](https://medium.com/@dickeyxxx/best-practices-for-building-angular-js-apps-266c1a4a6917).

Now I want to use an external library which internally works with [AMD from DOJO](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules/) and offers its functionality only via `require()` (or `define()`).

So let's wrap this external module in an Angular service:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('myService', function() {
    var result = {};
    require(['dependantModule'], function(mod) {
        result.mod = mod;
    });
    return result;
});
```

so that I can consume it:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('MyController', [ 'myService', function(myService) {
    console.log('mod: ' + myService.mod);
}]);
```

The console logs `mod: undefined` when the controller is consumed.
The reason is that `require()` executes it's callback asynchronously, so `result.mod` is set **after** `console.log()` gets executed.

Redesign my whole app to also use `require()` would technically be possible, but is no option anyway because an external library should not force me in one direction.

So what is the best way in AngularJS to use async AMD modules from external libraries?

### Update

After more research and trial'n'error, I've come up with

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('myService', [ '$q', function($q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    require(['dependantModule'], function(mod) {
        var result = {
            mod: mod
        };
        deferred.resolve(result);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}])

.controller('MyController', [ 'myService', function(myServicePromise) {
    myServicePromise.then(function(myService) {
        console.log('mod: ' + myService.mod);
    });
}]);
```

But is this the preferred way? Seems fishy, because consumers of the service must know that the injected thing is not the service itself, but only a promise which later resolves to the service.

### Update 2

As we saw, first declaring the service and `require`ing the module inside the service does not work. The other way around neither:

```
require(['dependantModule'], function(mod) {
    angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('myService', function() {
        return {
            mod: mod
        };
    });
});

angular.module('myApp')
.controller('MyController', [ 'myService', function(myService) {
    console.log('mod: ' + myService.mod);
}]);
```

because the require callback is executed **after** AngularJS will inject the service:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: myServiceProvider <- myService <- MyController
```

Comment: any luck with this? i'm looking for something like what you are trying to do here.